# How to recover a locally only committed branch in git?

Tags: git

Somehow my local git got corrupted and I am getting, "fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git". On one of the branches I have committed locally, but looks like that I have never pushed to the server. When I got a new repo on to a different folder, is there any way to recover that branch? In the new repo, when I try to checkout the branch, I am getting "the branch doesn't exist" message.

Thanks

Comment: That error means git cannot find a `.git/` directory in the current directory or any of its parents. That usually doesn't mean corruption, it means you're running git commands in the wrong directory. Your local repository might be fine. Are you *sure* you ran that command in the right directory? Another possibility is you copied or moved the repository and forgot the `.git/` directory.

Answer (score 1):

As probably you know. All the info about your braches and commits are inside a folder call `.git`

I have a problem long time ago like that. If you still have it the folder you should try to clone the repository (diferent folder) again and  copy the folders:

- `.git/refs` (here you can see the list of your branchs)
- `.git/objects` (you have the branch but you need the files info)

Hope you can recover your work!!!

Answer (score 0):

Added the older local repository as a remote of your new local repository, you can get those local branches in your old local repository.

Answer (score 0):

Worst case scenario, how about you clone from scratch, create a new branch and then copy the changed files from your corrupt local repository.